# How to distribute a Python program with external libraries

Tags: python, software-distribution

I have a Python program that uses the following libraries: Tkinter, NumPy, SciPy, SymPy, and Matplotlib. And probably it will include more libraries in the near future while being developed.

How can I distribute such a program to Mac, Windows, and Linux users, without requiring users to install the right version of each library, and hopefully by just downloading a single file and executing it?

What I initially wanted was compiling the program into a static binary program, but it seems that it's not an easy goal.

Probably I can ask users to install Python, but that's the maximum requirement that I can ask for them, and I want to avoid it if possible.

I don't care about hiding the code at all; in the end I will distribute both the code and the program. What I want is to make the program very easy for any user to download and run it.

Even such an advice as 'a Python program is not suitable for such a distribution' is welcome. I had a fair amount of experience with distributing C programs but I don't know what to expect with a Python program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenient, you could try something like [pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki).
It will package all of needed module into one folder or or one executable as you like. And it can run in all platforms.

The simple command to make a directory contains an executable file and all needed library is

```
$pyinstaller --onedir --name=directory_name --distpath="path_to_put_that_directory" "path to your main_program.py"
```

You can change `--onedir` into `--onefile` to make that folder into an one executable file which has all the thing it need to run inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Setuptools to do the packaging stuff .
It create [eggs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs), which are the equivalent of jars.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#using-setuptools-and-easyinstall

https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I guess such a distribution assumes that the user already installed Python, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Py2exe](http://py2exe.org/) , even though you risk the application becoming bigger than it already is, and some packages need to be installed manually .